# Edit an input tag with type number and onInputChange is only executed when enter is hit

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do I edit an input tag with type number and onInputChange is only executed when enter is hit?

Let's say I have an input tag in my JSX render function like this

```
<input type='number' value={this.state.currentIndex} onChange={event => this.onInputChange(event.target.value)}/>
```

Instead of firing off the function when a change occurs, I want to only fire onInputChange function when I hit the enter

I've tried using onKeyPress and onKeyDown along with default value to actually edit the value in the input but none of those seem to work.

The goal is to change the number of the input tag then hit enter for my function to fire off, while still passing it the new value I entered. 
Can someone please show me how this input tag should be formatted.

Comment: use the `keydown` event and check for key code `13`.

Comment: I've already tried the keydown event, the problem is making sure my value of the input tag matches the state, so when I manually change it and hit enter the task is run but when I'm going through my indexes the value/state gets updated.

Answer (score 1):

In that case, i think you should use [uncontrolled components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) and instead of using `onChange` event use `onKeyDown` and check the keyCode. **KeyCode of enter key is 13** so if the keycode of key pressed by user is 13 then do the task that you want to do.

Use this:

```
<input  onKeyDown={event => this.onInputChange(event)}/>

onInputChange(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        //do the task
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to pass the value and then call `.keyCode` on it?